# Count array inside array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array of Object as:

Expected O/P : **{alpha:4, beta:8}**

For this I tried as:

```js
const apple = [{
    name: 'alpha',
    details: [{
      "attachment": [123, 456]
    }, {
      "attachment": [1454, 1992]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'beta',
    details: [{
      "attachment": ["12", 189]
    }, {
      "attachment": ["maggi", 1890, 2000]
    }, {
      "attachment": [1990, 2001, 2901]
    }]
  }
];

const appleDetails = [];

for (let i = 0; i < apple.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < apple[i].details.length; j++) {
    const {
      name
    } = apple[i];
    const {
      attachment
    } = apple[i].details[j]
    appleDetails.push({
      name,
      attachment
    })
  }
}

let appleData = [];
appleDetails.forEach(({
  name,
  attachment
}) => {
  attachment.forEach((attatchId) => {
    appleData.push({
      name,
      _id: attatchId
    })
  })
})

const eachAppleCount = appleData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = item.name
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    acc[key] = 0
  }
  acc[key] += 1
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(eachAppleCount);
```

This gives the O/P as required i.e. : **{alpha:4, beta:8}**

But the process involved is too much, is there any more efficient way such that,by using:

```
const apple = [{
    name: 'alpha',
    details: [{
        "attachment": [123, 456]
    }, {
        "attachment": [1454, 1992]
    }]
}, {
    name: 'beta',
    details: [{
        "attachment": ["12", 189]
    }, {
        "attachment": ["maggi", 1890, 2000]
    }, {
        "attachment": [1990, 2001, 2901]
    }]
}];
```

We can count the value for each apple name. If anyone needs any further information please do let me know.

Comment: Siva Pradhan did u see answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the work

```js
const apple = [{
  name: 'alpha',
  details: [{
    "attachment": [123, 456]
  }, {
    "attachment": [1454, 1992]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'beta',
  details: [{
    "attachment": ["12", 189]
  }, {
    "attachment": ["maggi", 1890, 2000]
  }, {
    "attachment": [1990, 2001, 2901]
  }]
}];

const result = apple.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.name] === undefined) acc[curr.name] = 0;
  curr.details.forEach((d) => (acc[curr.name] += d.attachment.length));
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try like below.

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - The **map()** method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
- Create new object as `{[a.name]: values}` where we use `[a.name]` inside `[]` so value from `a.name` will be set as object key.
- To get value we use [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) - The **flatMap()** method returns a new array formed by applying a given callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening the result by one level.
- Get all attachments with `a.details.flatMap(d => d.attachment)` and use `.length` to get total count as value.
- `map` will return result in format of array of objects.
- Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to club array of objects into single object.

```js
const apple = [
               { name: 'alpha', details: [{"attachment": [ 123, 456 ]}, {"attachment": [1454, 1992 ]} ]},
               {name: 'beta', details: [{"attachment": [ "12", 189 ]},{"attachment": ["maggi", 1890,2000 ]}, {"attachment": [1990, 2001,2901 ]} ]}
              ];

// map will return result in format of array of objects
let resultArr = apple.map(a => ({[a.name]: a.details.flatMap(d => d.attachment).length }));

// use reduce with spread syntax (...) to club array of objects into single object.
let result = resultArr.reduce((i, a) => ({...a, ...i}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: for the below input your answer won't be unique per apple name (u will have 2 entries of alpha apple which i believe is not good):

`const apple = [
  { name: 'alpha', details: [{ attachment: [123, 456] }, { attachment: [1454, 1992] }] },
  { name: 'alpha', details: [{ attachment: [123, 456, 222] }, { attachment: [1454, 1992] }] },
  {
    name: 'beta',
    details: [
      { attachment: ['12', 189] },
      { attachment: ['maggi', 1890, 2000] },
      { attachment: [1990, 2001, 2901] },
      { attachment: [1990, 2001, 2901] },
    ],
  },
];`

Comment: @LiorKaminsky, Yes, you are correct. If in case of OP can have multiple entries for `alpha` then he should better go with solution that you have provided.

Comment: The output seems different to what OP expects. This will create an object for each sum and return an array. OP expects a single object with the names as key and the count as values.

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks for pointing that out. Updated answer.

Comment: I'm personally not a big fan of continually spreading objects with `reduce()`. I'd probably go for making `resultArr` an array of pairs, then just use `Object.fromEntries()` on it: https://jsbin.com/kinayot/edit?js,console Another alternative is with your current code to call `resultArr.reduce((i, a) => Object.assign(i, a), {})`